# App store description special characters

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it not possible to use special characters like stars in App Store description anymore?

I get this error.:
Description must not contain markup language (for example, HTML tags).
Description must not contain the following characters: ★

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See http://www.tuaw.com/2013/04/23/apple-begins-restricting-use-of-special-characters-in-app-descri/

Answer (score 9):

Some unicode characters are still allowed. The following characters were tested and still work: • ◆ √ ▸

As for right now (April 26 2013) they work fine, but sure Apple can change the conditions again at any time.

Comment: ✓ is no longer supported.

Comment: ✓doesn't work, that's correct. But √ does as the answer correctly points out. They're different characters.

Answer (score 9):

I have just used • ◆ √ ▸ characters and it works! October, 2014

Answer (score 6):

These are also working as per May 17th 2015:

▶ ◀